# Подгрузка библиотеки внутрь через скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Нужно средствами JavaScript подгрузить с удаленного сервера (Google) jQuery.
Но так, что бы это было реализовано без добавление кода в HTML.
С файлом js можно извращаться как угодно.

Comment: "без добавления кода в HTML" Вы хотите вообще без тега `<script>` обойтись?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно добавить тэг `<script>` динамическим образом:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function() {
  $("#main").text("jQuery загружено!");
};
```

```html
<div id="main">jQuery загружается...</div>
```

Comment: 'head' лучше заменить на 'script'. Тег `<script>` будет наверняка (раз уж этот код выполняется), а вот `<head>` уже на совести разработчика

Comment: @tutankhamun Не понял. Даже на странице `about:blank`, `document.getElementsByTagName('head')` возвращает результат и `document.head` существует.

Comment: Такие теги как `<head>` и `<body>` вовсе не обязательно будут в верстке страницы, однако даже если они отсутсвуют многие браузеры уже давно автоматически их добавляют в dom. Так как этот `<script>` по добавлению jQuery гарантированно будет на странице, то можно использовать его как более надежную точку для добавления нового тега.

Answer (score 2):

Так делает Google!

```
var url = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
var elm = document.createElement('script');
    elm.src = url;
var col = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    col.parentNode.insertBefore(elm,col);
```